# Can Atmel ATTINY84 read I2C without adding any program or module?

Tags: arduino, i2c, attiny

I am recently connecting a gyroscope(L3G4200D) to ATTINY84,however, the gyroscope is using I2C and the ATTINY84 is using USI, as a result, I have some problem doing programming. I am using Arduino Uno to be the ISP, and I have connected the two wire of gyroscope to SDA and SCL pin on Attiny84 but it still doesn't work. Does anyone have any solution?

Answer (score 0):

This might help you solve your problem!

http://www.dexterindustries.com/howto/working-with-avr/any-port-any-pin-a-twi-master-for-attiny-atmega/

Answer (score 0):

Solution is in using right library which do software I2C. get https://github.com/svoisen/TinyWire library, connect 4 wires ( VCC, GND, SDA, SCL ), do not forget 2 pull-up 4K7 resistors to SDA/SCL. that's all.